# Python - Plotting specific time series range

Tags: python, plot, time-series

I have this  [txt](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5raop4h0ww0at62/D1.txt?dl=0) file, it contains one column with 456 elements, the first 6 are NaN's.
What I want to do is to match theses values with monthly dates, they go from january/1980 to december/2017.

Then I want to select only the months of October for each year (38 values) and make a line plot with them.
Since I'm fairly new to python this is what I have done:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
import numpy as np

#Read the txt data
input_data = pd.read_csv("D:\PCT\Datos_dummies\D1.txt",header = None )

#Create a list with the dates
dates =pd.date_range("1979-12-10","2017-12-07",freq="MS").strftime("%Y-%b").tolist()
```

I tried creating a data frame with the dates and the values with this:

```
#Create a data frame with the input data and the dates
df = pd.DataFrame({'Year':dates,'Ind':input_data},columns=["Year","Ind"])
```

But I get this error: `TypeError: 'long' object is not iterable`

I am not sure if I am making the right aproach or it's too complicated, does anyone know how to achieve this? In a similar or a differente way?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is the format of input_data, because you are trying to create a DataFrame with two columns, 'Year' and 'Ind' - but input_data is not a series, it is a DataFrame.

If you just want to add a column to the Dataframe you read from the file to add the dates, then simply doing this should add the new column to the input_data Dataframe you already have:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as mplt
import numpy as np

#Read the txt data
input_data = pd.read_csv("D:\PCT\Datos_dummies\D1.txt",header = None )

#Create a list with the dates
dates =pd.date_range("1979-12-10","2017-12-07",freq="MS").strftime("%Y-%b").tolist()

# Add the dates as a column to the 'input_data' DataFrame
input_data['Year'] = dates
```

Does that work for you?

If you want more information, please post more information about the contents of input_data: What are the columns and types.